# Alternative to Startup Disk Creator

Tags: 16.04, usb-creator, startup-disk-creator

Is there an alternative to **Startup Disk Creator** for creating a bootable usb in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: You can use UNetbootin or the dd command.

Comment: Yes, , UNetbootin worked fine on Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Best is the `dd` command as other alternatives including Startup Disk Creator often gives errors with newer versions of linux. The command is `sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/.iso of=/dev/sdx && sync`

Remember to unmount the USB and check the device name with `lsblk` command and change the `sdx` with appropriate device name in the command.

Answer (score 5):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) is a great alternative of **Startup Disk Creator**. **UNetbootin** (**Universal Netboot Installer**) is a cross-platform utility that can create live USB systems and can load a variety of system utilities or install various Linux distributions and other operating systems without a CD. You can install **UNetbootin** in Ubuntu 16.04 by running the commands given below from terminal :-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

References : [UNetbootin - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin)